# How instantiating an inner class in Java really works?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm making an instance from an **inner** class, but I can't understand what does this syntax mean.

```
OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();

OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

I know that I can't get an object from an inner class without getting an object from the outer one `OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();`, then we use the object from the outer class **outerObject** to get an instance from the inner class `outerObject.new InnerClass();`, so what does **OuterClass.InnerClass** actually means as it is not explained in the Java documentation as it states:

*To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax* `OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();`

Comment: `OuterClass.InnerClass` is just the classes name, like you're not just Ahmed, you're Maad.Ahmed. But it is just a part from the name, because the full name would be `the.package.name.OuterClass.InnerClass`. What `OuterClass` means is already clear in this context, so you don't need to explicitly name the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the name of the class, and it's likely named this way to make it easier for the compiler to find the definition.

If you declare your variable as just being of type `InnerClass`, it will look for the file `InnerClass.java`, but there is no such file.

The dot notation indicates that it's actually a member of `OuterClass`, so it will look for the definition within the file `OuterClass.java`.

This is the same thing as using a class from a library,

```java
com.example.MyLibrary.ExternalClass myExternalObject;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the syntactic meaning is as follows:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass(); 
           InnerClass                                             The class InnerClass
          .                                                       which is an inner class of
OuterClass                                                        OuterClass
                      innerObject                                 has an instance named innerObject
                                  =                               which is assigned the value
                                                new InnerClass()  of a new InnerClass instance
                                               .                  such that when you use
                                                                  OuterClass.this from within
                                                                  InnerClass methods invoked on
                                                                  innerObject, it refers to
                                    outerObject                   outerObject.
```

The key here is that inner classes are created through a reference to the outer class. If your InnerClass is static (one InnerClass for the entire OuterClass class), you'll see that the reference to the outer class is static:

```
static class InnerClass { ... }
...
//Initialization will become:
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
                                        ^ this part is a static OuterClass reference
```

On the other hand, in your current scenario (InnerClass is not static), the inner class must be created with a reference to the OuterClass in the form of an object - `outerObject`. Furthermore, you are actually able to access `outerObject` from within InnerClass by referring to `OuterClass.this`:

> OuterClass.java

```
public class OuterClass
{
  class InnerClass
  {
    public OuterClass getOuterClassReference()
    {
      return OuterClass.this;
    }
  }
}
```

> Main.java

```
class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();
    OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass(); 
    System.out.println(outerObject);
    System.out.println(innerObject.getOuterClassReference());
    System.out.println(outerObject == innerObject.getOuterClassReference());
  }
}
```

**Output:**

> OuterClass@36baf30c
>   OuterClass@36baf30c
>   true

Here, `36baf30c` in the output is an arbitrary memory address. These two output lines will always be the same. As you can clearly see, referring to `OuterClass.this` from within an InnerClass instance will return the OuterClass instance that was provided at initialization. This is part of the reason that you can't just call `new InnerClass()` - the reference `OuterClass.this` cannot be initialized properly without being provided with an instance.

Comment: I got it by 90% but I didn't understand this part if you could please add more details __(such that when you use OuterClass.this...etc.)__

Comment: @AhmedMaad Uhm, could you explain the part that confuses you? Ok, I'm making a code repository to demonstrate.

Comment: The part starting from __= outerObject.new InnerClass()__

Comment: @AhmedMaad I've tried to demonstrate with an example. Hopefully it helps you clarify the second part.

Answer (score 1):

JVM does not make a difference between `OuterClass` and `InnerClass`: both classes are POJO and separate classes. But `InnerClass` is not `static` and therefore it has internal `this` refers to the instance of `OuterClass` (therefore it should be created only with existed `OuterClass` instance)

```
public class OuterClass {
    public class InnerClass {
        public OuterClass getOuterClassReference() {
            return OuterClass.this;
        }
    }
}

OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();
OuterClass.InnterClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass(); // innerObject has this reference to outerObject
```

---

```
public class OuterClass {
    public static class InnerClass {}
}

OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = new OuterClass.InnerClass(); // innerObject does not have this reference to outerObject
```

---

In other words, you can emulate `InnterClass` by yourself like this:

```
public class OuterClass {   
}

public class InnerClass {
    private final OuterClass outer;

    public InnerClass(OuterClass outer) {
        this.outer = outer;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Outerclass.Innerclass` is just a part of the Innerclass' full path.
The full path would be something like `packagename.Outerclass.Innerclass`.

Thus, 
`OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();` 
is really no different from something like:
`java.util.ArrayList<T> varName = new java.util.ArrayList<T>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the inner class as static member of OuterClass

```
public class OuterClass {
    public static class StaticInnerClass {
        int i = 0;

        public String call() {
            i++;
            return this.getClass().getName() + " i=" + i;
        }
    }
}
```

so defining the static inner class the compile knows that members is a class, the memory area is instanced at compile time (it is accessible in static way) and you can apply the new operator and the new operator instances the class in another memory area.

For example in a main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581397/how-instantiating-an-inner-class-in-java-really-works
         *
         * @@@ New instance of Inner class
         */
        OuterClass.StaticInnerClass staticInnerClass = new OuterClass.StaticInnerClass();

        System.out.println(staticInnerClass.call());
        System.out.println(staticInnerClass.call());


        staticInnerClass = new OuterClass.StaticInnerClass();
        System.out.println("\n" + staticInnerClass.call());
        System.out.println(staticInnerClass.call());
    }
}
```

with output

```
// new of inner class and i = 0
innerclass.OuterClass$StaticInnerClass i=1
innerclass.OuterClass$StaticInnerClass i=2

// new of inner class and i = 0 
innerclass.OuterClass$StaticInnerClass i=1
innerclass.OuterClass$StaticInnerClass i=2
```

References: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html.